# how can we access div element text using div id

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
<div id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_AddressLinesPanel">
    <div>
        2nd Floor
    </div>
    <div>
        1801 Morris Avenue
    </div>
    <div>
        Primary: 432567865
    </div>
</div>
```

1. How can i get only 2nd floor
2. How can i print only number(432567865)

Answer (score 0):

element.text return the text of the element or first direct child.

You can use css selector, after getting the div with id.

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_id(ID)
# This will get first div child
floor = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#id > div:nth-child(1)')
second = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#id > div:nth-child(2)')
# OR
childs = element.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
# This will return all child divs in an array
```

You can also use `element.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)` to search within element (which we got by `driver.find_element_by_id(ID)`)

While css selectors are faster to use, you can also use XPath if  you like.

Comment: did not worked. i want to use on this     try:
      agencyAddress = browser.find_element_by_id('MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_AddressLinesPanel').text
     except:
      agencyAddress = 'No address'
     print(agencyAddress)

Comment: here i need to get nth child data

Answer (score 0):

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_AddressLinesPanel"]/div[contains(.,"Primary")]').split(':')[1])
```

use split and contains

Comment: did not worked i tried on try:
      phone = browser.find_element_by_id('MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_Phone1Panel').text
      # phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_Phone1Panel"]/div[contains(.,"Primary")]').split(':')[1]
     except:
      phone = 'No number'
     print(phone)

Comment: what did you get as output

Answer (score 0):

To print the text *`2nd floor`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_AddressLinesPanel > div").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_AddressLinesPanel']/div").text)
  ```

To print the text *`432567865`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_AddressLinesPanel']//div[contains(., 'Primary')]").text.split(':')[1])
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_AddressLinesPanel > div"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_AddressLinesPanel']/div"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```

To print the text *`432567865`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='MainCopy_ctl13_presentJob_AddressLinesPanel']//div[contains(., 'Primary')]"))).text.split(':')[1])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)